# Read one file name "Only" and skip to next directory - PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code which reads all filnames from each directory, but I want it to read one filename "only" and skip to the next directory.

```
<?php
$dir = "/images/";

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
      echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
?>
```

How can I read only one filename, then skip to the next directory to read "only" first filename and so on.  Please let me know if you require any more information.

Comment: if it doesn't matter which file you read then just put a `break;` in your while loop or don't even go in a loop just take the `$file = readdir($dh);`PS: In linux OS be aware of `.` and `..`

Comment: @X10nD what abount santa's suggestion?

Comment: @AyyanarG santa If there are more than one directories and a break is put will it read into the other directories?

Comment: @Santa'shelper can you post that as an answer so I can accept. The break worked with my code though.

Comment: @AyyanarG How do I "break" more than "1"?

Comment: for that you have to use counter as Alexander suggested

Comment: if u guys need to read recursive dir read thats a another case you need to make a custom function which is calling itself in case of `$file` is a dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it doesn't matter which file you read then just put a `break;` in your while loop or don't even go in a loop just take the `$file = readdir($dh);`
PS: In linux OS be aware of `.` and `..` Also look up [scabdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function

Comment: I put a break in the loop
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
      echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";
##break;
    }
But that just gives me a single filename.

Comment: maybe we misunderstood but i thought you already asking "How can I read **only one filename**, then skip to the next directory"

Comment: yes thats what I actually wanted but when I put placed in your suggestions and worked on it, I had to get about 5 filenames, so asked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain counter here to do the same.

Do like this:

```
$dir = "/images/";

if (is_dir($dir)){
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
        echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";
        break;
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
```

Let me know for more help!

Comment: why counter break in while will do the same

Comment: In the first answer it echo the directory name only
- In the second answer it reads only the first directory, first file name.

Comment: @Alexander, santa's suggestion worked, I put a break 1; to my code ;)

Comment: Ok. Thanks to santa's suggestion. You enjoy @X10nD